# Disable animated gifs using javascript and the canvas tag?

Tags: javascript, animated-gif

Here's one way i've made work in chrome:  http://jsfiddle.net/quickredfox/7k3jN but you'll run into some problems trying to implement that cross-browser, namely: security restrictions.

The problem with my example is that it replaces the original image with a canvas tag. That sucks, I loose all CSS rules that would normally work for what should normally be there.

My original idea was to replace the image with the output of canvas.toDataURL() as the src attribute on a new Image() object, but seeing as the image is hosted on another domain I get security restriction errors. Again, that sucks.

Can anyone think of a nice way to do this that doesn't suck and would work well for preventing animated avatars on a collection of tweets displayed in a browser?

Oh, and I mean totally 100% in the browser, no server-side assist.

Comment: do you have any control over the HTML ?

Comment: 100%, I build the entire page using ExtJs 4 templates. But not the image host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since these images are apparently being hosted on Twitter and Twitter does not (I checked) set the CORS headers (the bastards!), you *cannot* do this browser side.

If it were me, I would set up a server on [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/)'s free tier that would run [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) and [flatten the image](http://nadiana.com/pil-tips-converting-png-gif) to PNG.

Comment: Yeah, something like that or some [GAE](http://code.google.com/appengine/) hack is all I've found reasonable so far. But I have need for so many of those little server-side assists here and there I'm starting to think I should jot them down bundle them up and get myself some startup funding. lol

Comment: I checked: GAE does not support PIL (the bastards!  My free ice-cream is the wrong flavor!) PIL cannot (afaik) be scripted, but ImageMagick can be.  You make an site that you post an image URL and a IM script and it returns the modified image, and you have the beginnings of a fantastically unprofitable start-up.

Comment: Ah, but google.appengine.api.images exists and apparently can convert from GIF to PNG.  You don't get a lot of control, but it's easier than an AWS solution (and you don't need to give them your credit card).

Answer (score 2):

There's a large chance that this is just too much heavy lifting, but I'll mention it just in case.

If you use jQuery to perform the image replacement, there's a plugin that you can use which allows you to copy the CSS of an object to another object:

http://upshots.org/?p=192

Insert your canvas element, copy the source CSS from the GIF and remove the GIF.

The fact that it uses window.getComputedStyle should hopefully mean that that you get implied CSS as well as stuff that happens via class name.
In fact, it's probably easy enough to take the code for that plugin and turn it into something that doesn't require jQuery.

Hope this helps or inspires!

Comment: No, I definitely do not want that approach where I copy element's styles and such, I prefer the bloat elsewhere.

Comment: If you control the HTML as you've said, then perhaps you should simply add a wrapper to the image and have the CSS applied to that, then if it's an animated gif, remove and replace as you're doing. the same CSS should still be inherited.

Comment: I give a point for this because it's a good and valid answer. But I really wish I could re-use my code in a place where I have no control over the HTML or CSS. Because I feel that's the obvious next step.

Comment: I agree; and if nothing else - I think it would at least be awesome to have a programmatic way to stop animated gifs from animating, or at least only going one cycle. As it stands though, if you have no control over the markup and you have to honor computed styles, then I think replicating the elements style is the only way forward. I'll keep an eye on this in case anything else pops up of course, good question!

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the server that is hosting images, then there's about a 10% chance that putting [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) headers will work.  Without it, any solution that does work would also be a security hole (and therefore a bug in the browser).

**EDIT:** sometimes, long shots pay off: [CORS is supposed to work](http://blog.chromium.org/2011/07/using-cross-domain-images-in-webgl-and.html)!

Comment: I like this idea, though the reason I hinted on this being used to display tweet user's avatars, I have no control whatsoever regarding the  servers hosting the images.